# Skip code at start of do-while loop without using a butchered for-loop C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, control-flow, .net-6.0

I have a do-while loop that's rather large but simply put it's a part of my network-thread code.

The control flow looks a bit like this

```cs
switch(Task.WhenAny(tasks))
{
    case -1:
        //...
        break;

    case task1_id:
        //...
        break;

    case udp_receive_id:
        {
            ValueTask<SocketReceiveMessageFromResult> udp_receive_vtask = default; // default to avoid not-instantiated errors
            SocketReceiveMessageFromResult Result = udp_receive_task.Result;
            goto skip_vtask_getresult; // throws an error because skip_vtask_getresult is out of scope.

            do
            {
                Result = udp_receive_vtask.Result;
                skip_vtask_getresult:
                // ...
                udp_receive_vtask = _socket_udp.ReceiveMessageFromAsync(/*...*/)
                // ...
            }
            while(udp_receive_vtask.IsCompleted)
            tasks[udp_receive_id] = udp_receive_task = udp_receive_vtask.AsTask();
        }
        break;

    case task3_id:
        //...
        break;
}
```

So far I can only think of this, but imo it's ugly, and there's surely a better way?

```cs
for(Result = udp_receive_task.Result; true; Result = udp_receive_vtask.Result)
{
    //...
    if(!udp_receive_vtask.IsCompleted)
        break;
}
```

Is there any way I could go about implementing this, without:

1. casting my ValueTask into a full blown Task every time.
2. having to refactor the code into a separate method (as this is within a "considered" hot path).

It's code running on .NET 6 and wholly contained within a single function with mostly local variables (as only sparingly using ldfld makes everything a lot faster) this is the reason why I would like to avoid refactoring the contained code into another function, as it would undoubtable slow the hot path down a bit.

A quick explanation on why its done like this is, that this is the general network thread and its expected to handle ticking clients, and receiving bulk UDP-packets, which is why I want to use Value Tasks. A considered and very likely scenario is that while the thread is ticking the individual clients it could be receiving multiple packets and being able to quickly without any thread switching receive and process these stacked packets at once would greatly speed up the whole network stack and help reduce latency experienced by thread switching.

**Note**: if you don't know why ldfld is much slower then ldloc, its because the JIT no longer can optimize out external sets. So no matter the scenario every time it compiles ldfld it will always get the field from heap, where as ldloc the JIT knows it wont change between ldloc's and as such will reuse the registry value when possible. Making a hot path considerably faster. [check here for a clearer representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27111593/why-is-setting-a-field-many-times-slower-than-getting-a-field)

Comment: Why not just remove the `goto`?

Comment: @KlausGütter because I don't want to execute the first line in the do-while.

I want to have that goto, but I'm not allowed to.

Comment: Why? It does not hurt to access `udp_receive_vtask.Result` twice.

Comment: @KlausGütter um, YES IT DOES. Please Actually read about ValueTasks, they are a lot more unsafe than normal Tasks, and as a rule of thumb, you consume them ONCE that means you access .Result once or your Cast it to a Task once.

the ValueTask object can be reused/recycled by the underlying implementer. so no do not access a ValueTask after you have consumed it.

for more info [read Stephens devblock](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/)